# What this error is complaining about while running test on RepositoryController Asp.Net Core?

Tags: asp.net-core

I'm trying to run test on the repository Controller 'PeoppleRepositoryController.cs.
I get the below error and I couldn't figure out what exactly it is complaining about.
Can anyone please explain what I need to do to fix this issue?

> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetService(IServiceProvider sp, Type type, Type requiredBy, bool isDefaultParameterRequired)

The full stack trace can be seen on the image below:

The controller is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Personkartotek.DAL;
using Personkartotek.Models;
using Personkartotek.Persistence;


namespace Personkartotek.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class PeopleRepositoryController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IUnitOfWork _uoWork;

        public PeopleRepositoryController(IUnitOfWork uoWork)
        {
            _uoWork = uoWork;
        }

        // GET: api/PeopleRepository
        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<Person> GetPersons()
        {
            return _uoWork._People.GetAll();
        }

        // GET: api/PeopleRepository/5
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetPerson([FromRoute] int id)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            var person = _uoWork._People.Get(id);

            if (person == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return Ok(person);
        }

        //GET: api/PeopleRepository/
        [HttpGet("AtAdr/{id}")]
        public IActionResult GetPersonsResidingAtAddress([FromRoute] int AddressId)
        {
            var ResidingPersons = _uoWork._People.GetAllPersonsById(AddressId);

            return Ok(ResidingPersons);
        }

        // PUT: api/PeopleRepository/5
        [HttpPut("{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> PutPerson([FromRoute] int id, [FromBody] Person person)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            if (id != person.PersonId)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            if (!PersonExists(id))
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            _uoWork._People.Put(person);

            return NoContent();
        }

        // POST: api/PeopleRepository
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> PostPerson([FromBody] Person person)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            _uoWork._People.Add(person);
            _uoWork.Complete();

            return CreatedAtAction("GetPerson", new { id = person.PersonId }, person);
        }

        // DELETE: api/PeopleRepository/5
        [HttpDelete("{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> DeletePerson([FromRoute] int id)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid) {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            var person =  _uoWork._People.Get(id);
            if (person == null) {
                return NotFound();
            }

            _uoWork._People.Remove(person);
            _uoWork.Complete();

            return Ok(person);
        }

        private bool PersonExists(int id)
        {
            return _uoWork.Exist(id);
        }
    }
}
```

IUnitOfWork file:

```
using Personkartotek.DAL.IRepositories;

namespace Personkartotek.DAL
{
    public interface IUnitOfWork : IDisposable
    {
        IPeopleRepository _People { get; }

        int Complete();

        bool Exist(int id);
    }
}
```

My Startup.cs file set ups:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Personkartotek.DAL;
using Personkartotek.Models.Context;
using Personkartotek.Persistence;
using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger;


namespace Personkartotek
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
            });

            services.AddDbContext<ModelsContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("PersonkartotekDB")));

            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);


        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            }

            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseCookiePolicy();

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It complaints because it doesn't know how to create an object of `IUnitOfWork` which is a dependency on your controller.

So to resolve the issue you need to instruct the framework on what implementation of `IUnitOfWork` you want to use. Typically you are doing it in your `Startup.ConfigureServices` method. For exmaple:

```
public class Startup
{
   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
   {
      services.AddTransient<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWorkImplementation>();
   } 
}
```

Where `UnitOfWorkImplementation` is a class that implement `IUnitOfWork`

Comment: yes, I think the best starting point to read about it is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-2.1#overview-of-dependency-injection

Comment: is this correct:             services.AddScoped<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();

Comment: Is there any reason you suggest Transient?

Comment: I specified `Transient` for the sake of example. You would need to choose the object lifetime based on our implementation. For example if your `UnitOfWork` object is thread-safe, doesn't have any state or expensive to create - you may consider using `AddSingleton` instead